# IOS Swift: Run a block of code once before init method (constructor)

Tags: ios, swift

In IOS SWIFT, how can I implement a similar functionality like ***static constructor provides in C#***.

**That is:**

1. Execucte a block of code before init method (first code block to execute in class)
2. Gets called automatically
3. Execute only once in life cycle of class

This is to set a global translation mapping to encode instance of a class with the provided name rather that real class name (the class name is 'Order').

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Order.self, forClassName: "OldModuleName.Order")
```

Writing an old APP (written in SWIFT 1.2) from the begininig and the the project name is different, therefore the Module name is different than old version.

I need to run that bit of code mentioned above just before initlaize the class and once.

```
class Order: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var orderID: Int = 0
    var description: String = ""

    // NEED TO RUN THIS LINE BEFORE INIT METHOD >>>>
    // NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Order.self, forClassName: "OldModuleName.Order")

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)    
    {
        self.orderID = (aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "OrderID"))
        self.description= (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Description") as? String) ?? ""
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)    
    {        
        aCoder.encode(self.orderID, forKey: "OrderID")
        aCoder.encode(self.description, forKey: "Description")
    }
}
```

**EDITS**

I tried writing a static constant like below and callling it at the "***required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)***" method (Because this class conforms to NSCoding protocol NOT the default init method gets called in this case)

```
static let ConfigureEncodeTranslationMapping: Void =    
{               
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Order.self, forClassName: "OldModuleName.Order")        
    return()    
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)    
{
    // call static constant here to test
    Order.ConfigureEncodeTranslationMapping

    self.orderID = (aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "OrderID"))
    self.description= (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Description") as? String) ?? ""
}
```

BUT APP crashing saying

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (OldModuleName.Order) for key (NS.objects) because no class named "OldModuleName.Order" was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target). If the class was renamed, use setClassName:forClass: to add a class translation mapping to NSKeyedUnarchiver*

Comment: So the question is how to implement the Once pattern?

Comment: Why not do it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes can do that. Looking if there is a way to do it within the class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a class method called `load()` that called automatically per class load and once per app launch. but it defines Objective-C class method 'load', which is not permitted by **Swift**. You can use an Objective-C class and bridge it back to the Swift.

Try this to see the issue:

```
override class func load() {
    print("Loaded")
}
```

This is a dynamic behavior and **Swift** is static! So you can't do this in swift without helping the Objective-C

### Similar but not same

You can have a static constant and call it once (or more, doesn't matter):

```
class Order {
    static let loadOnce: Void = { print("Loaded") }()
}

Order.loadOnce
Order.loadOnce
Order.loadOnce
Order.loadOnce
```

Looking at the output shows it just getting called `once` and no need to load the class. So you can use the following to make sure it gets called before initialization completed.

```
init() { Self.loadOnce }
```

Or even before calling `super.init`

```
override init() {
    Self.loadOnce
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: Hi tried calling a static constant like you suggest. Did call the static constant as shown in EDITS section in my question (because this class conforms to 'NSCoding' protocol, the default init method not gets fired). So App crash with the message shown there

Comment: The error doesn’t mention it related to the initializer, right? Did you test the ‘load’ method?

Comment: Yes, the error is because this is NOT running before init method begins. If I call this "Order.ConfigureEncodeTranslationMapping", just before the place where I initialise the object of this class then works OK. I am doing that way for the moment until get this sorted. Like if there is a way that's there if can do within the same class itself. I will check 'load' method and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @JibW Can you explain why it matters that this should happen just before the first instantiation of this class?

Comment: @Matt, if this code block (line) does NOT execute before first initilaization, APP crashing with the message shown in EDITS section in my question. Reason: SWIFT treats 'Order' class as different than prev versions's one as Module name is different this time.... Of course it doen't matter to run this line every time but unnecessary. Running ones before first init is enough

Comment: Yes, in Objective C we used to use `initialize` for that. But in Swift you would use a static or a known earlier event.